# Wait for axios response before execute code in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I'm trying to register event listeners into my `useEffect` hook, like this

```
               useEffect(() => {
               const dataFromAxios = await axios.get('/axios-data');
               window.addEventListener('load', () => {
                console.log("Action for load")

                window.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
                    console.log("Action for focus")
                }, false);

                window.addEventListener("message", async (e) => {
                    const { data: dataFromMessage } = e;
    
                    if (dataFromMessage) { // true or false

                        if (dataFromAxios && dataFromMessage.isUserExist) {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    } 
                    }
                }, false);
            });
    } )
```

But I need `dataFromAxios` before register `addEventListener`. How can I handle this and wait for axios data before execute code?

Comment: Hi, please check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way, you can add event listeners after your data is ready.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const getData = async ( ) => {
    const dataFromAxios =  await axios.get('/axios-data');
    setData(dataFromAxios);
}

useEffect(() => {
   getData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
   if(data) {
      // do what you want with the data here
   }
}, [data])
```

The code above does:

- fetch data after the first paint
- if data is fetched, add event listeners

The second useEffect has data state set in its dependency array. That means if the dependency array's value changes, it will trigger the side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a async function in useEffect, which is executed immediately and then check whether the data is defined and in the if condition execute the event listeners.
An article of how to use async await in useEffect [link](https://dev.to/stlnick/useeffect-and-async-4da8)